# Transform a specific type of argument using templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I want to have a utility function U that calls another function F after transforming a specific type of argument. The specific type of argument is `vector<LibraryClass>` and this is fixed. The transformation is from `vector<LibraryClass>` to `special_vector<LibraryClass>`.

The call will look like this:

```
vector<LibraryClass> a, c;
OtherType b, d, ...;
U(F, a, b, c, d, ...);
```

I want the above be equivalent to:

```
F(special_vector(a), b, special_vector(c), d, ...);
```

I really want is a very short solution. What do you think is the simplest way to implement this? I'm only interested in approaches not code.

Comment: C++98, C++11, C++14 or C++17?

Comment: Define a helper template function that returns its parameter. Specialize it for the `vector<LibraryClass>`, in the obvious manner. Now, write your wrapper function that forwards all of its arguments via the helper template function. Can't get any easier than that.

Comment: tagged as c++11

Comment: and the arguments functions `U()` and `F()` are known and fixed or of type variadic templates?

Comment: the number of arguments are not known, so need to use variadic templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshing out what [Sam Varshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841546/transform-a-specific-type-of-argument-using-templates/46841704#comment80630991_46841546) said

```
template<typename T>
T&& transform(T&& t) { return std::forward<T>(t); }

special_vector<LibraryClass> transform(const std::vector<LibraryClass>& v)
{
    return {v};
}

template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
void U(Fn f, Args&&... args)
{
    f(std::forward<Args>(transform(args))...);
}
```

You might want to either add more overloads for `transform(std::vector<LibraryClass>&&)` and all that, or SFINAE on the type.

Comment: Thanks, Sam and Passer, this is indeed simpler than what I was thinking of!